# Does Ruby support var references like PHP?

Tags: php, ruby, reference

In PHP, you can make two variables point to the same data.

```
$a = 'foo';
$b = 'bar';
$a =& $b;
echo $a // Outputs: bar
echo $b // Outputs: bar
```

What we are trying to do in Ruby is set `@app_session` to be equal to `session[@current_app[:uid]]`. So we only have to deal with `@app_session` in our app, and everything is automatically saved to the session.

Is there a way to do this in Ruby? After 15 minutes of reading, googling, and asking around here at the office, we're still lost... lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All variables in Ruby are references to an object.

```
a = b
```

means that a and b point to the same object.  That's why when you want to copy a given object, you need to write

```
a = b.dup
```

Writing

```
@app_session = session[@current_app[:uid]]
```

points to the same object so you should be fine.

EDIT: you can verify this this way:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = 1
=> 1
irb(main):002:0> b = a
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> p a.object_id
3
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> p b.object_id
3
```

Comment: Be aware that b.dup is a shallow copy. You can use a = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(b)) for a deep copy.

Comment: Don't forget Object#clone, which is slightly different. Quoting from Pickaxe: "While `clone` is used to duplicate an object, `dup` is typically uses the class of the descendent object to create the new instance." Errr, FWIW.

Comment: You might want to change your example to use something different than Fixnums, like Strings: Fixnums, true, false, nil and symbols are immediate values which *always* have the same object_id. So, if you changed e.g. b=a to b=1 you would still get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

I'm still pretty new to Ruby, and no one at work is a Ruby-God yet... lol

`@app_session = session[@current_app[:uid]]` worked just like a charm. I didn't try it, cause in PHP world where I'm from there'd be no point in even trying... lol :)

Answer (score 3):

Variables and constants are pointers to memory locations. Ruby does this by defaut, so you don't have to "emulate" the PVP behaviour by hand. Evidence:

```
a = "hi"
b = a
a.upcase!
puts a
# => "HI"
puts b
# => "HI"
```

As for your `@app_session` question, I'd do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def app_session
    session[@current_app[:uid]]
  end
end
```

This lets you call the method 'app_session', so that you can easily change the implementation later on. (Say, if you find out that you need to use a constant instead of an instance variable, or whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with leethal and Keltia. Just one thing to point out:

When you assign some string to a variable, you ALWAYS create a new String object, by doing so.

```
a = "foo"  # Create a new String object and make a refer this object.
b = "bar"  # Create a new String object and make b refer this object.
a = b      # Make b refer the object created in the first step.
a = "blah" # Create a new String object and make a refer this object. (!)
puts b     # But(!) b is still "foo", because it still refers the "foo" object.
# => "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't  this the default for all ruby objects? It wouldn't make sense to copy an object every time.