# Multiple initialization of auto-vivifying hashes using a new operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization, reference, autovivification

I would like to initialize several [auto-vivifying hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148747/is-auto-initialization-of-multi-dimensional-hash-array-possible-in-ruby-as-it-is) by one-line expression. So far I came to an extra method for the `AutoHash` object:

```
class AutoHash < Hash
  ...
  def few(n=0)
    Array.new(n) { AutoHash.new }
  end
```

which allows me to do the following

```
a, b, c = AutoHash.new.few 3
```

However, I feel that one can make the following sentence possible by defining a new operator `:=`

```
a := b := c = AutoHash.new
```

Could you help me to implement this?

---

Do I have to use [superators](http://github.com/jicksta/superators)?

```
require 'superators'

class AutoHash < Hash
  ...
  superator ":=" do |operand|
    if operand.kind_of? Hash
      ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end
```

---

**Update:** Now I see that the operator needs to be defined outside the class. Is it possible to define such object clone operator?

---

**Update2** More clear definition of method `few`, thanks to Joshua

---

**References**

1. http://www.linux-mag.com/cache/7432/1.html
2. [Does Ruby support var references like PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460663/does-ruby-support-var-references-like-php)
3. http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/deepcopy.htm

Comment: You realize that your current a = b = c = AutoHash.new.few 3 will make all the variables refer to *the same* Hash instance? If you don't want that, the implementation of the := operator probably needs to invoke clone() and you run into the usual 'do I want a deep clone?' problems.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I have fixed it. Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you ask for `a := b := c := AutoHash.new.few 3` I think (not sure I understand your desire) that you really want `a,b,c=Autohash.new.few 3`

---

Why does few take variable args, when you only ever use the first?

I also find your creation of the return value to be confusing, maybe try

```
def few(n=0) 
  Array.new(n) { AutoHash.new } 
end
```

---

Beyond that, it seems like `few` should be a class method. `a,b,c=AutoHash.few 3` which will work if you defined few on the class:

```
def AutoHash.few(n=0)
  Array.new(n) { AutoHash.new }
end
```

---

If `a,b,c=AutoHash.few 3` isn't what you're looking for, and you *really* want to implement your own operator, then check out *Hacking parse.y*, which was a talk given at RubyConf 2009.  You can watch the presentation at http://rubyconf2009.confreaks.com/19-nov-2009-17-15-hacking-parsey-tatsuhiro-ujihisa.html and you can see the slides at http://www.slideshare.net/ujihisa/hacking-parsey-rubyconf-2009

Comment: Joshua, thanks for the answer. Variable args are not needed indeed (just a bad habit). I want to use `a := b := c = AutoHash.new` for initialization (I have probably changed my question when you were typing)

Comment: I don't understand what the := operator is supposed to do. I have read the new version of the question several times. The old version made me think you wanted the behaviour that `a,b,c` gives. But now I cannot tell.

Comment: Basically, I want a magic operator for deep cloning of objects. So that the sentence `a := b := c = AutoHash.new` would give me three not-related hashes. So far I have to use `few` method of my class for that, which is less convenient.

Comment: I see. One problem you will have is that Ruby has poor support for deep copying (probably in part because -- without complete immutability -- the concept itself suffers from certain serious issues -- but still, it could be much better). You have the dup and clone methods for generating shallow copies, and there is some sort of cumbersome workaround using marshalling. Regardless of which approach you take, this will need to be addressed.

Comment: Here is a potential alternative http://pastie.org/private/ayj1vglvadv5bf8orza It adds the few method to object, then it is available to everyone. If the object having few invoked on it is a class, then populates the array with new instances of that class, otherwise, it dups the object. To get deep copy behaviour, you have to define what that means for you in each object you are using. Here I wrote my own dup method for AutoHash that also dups keys and values. And it takes the first arg as how many to create, and the rest / any blocks get forwarded on.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Joshua! I have decided to open a new question instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171118/how-to-create-an-operator-for-deep-copy-cloning-of-objects-in-ruby