# How to handle combination []+= for auto-vivifying hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, operator-keyword, autovivification

In order to implement auto-vivification of Ruby hash, one can employ the following class

```
class AutoHash < Hash
  def initialize(*args)
    super()
    @update, @update_index = args[0][:update], args[0][:update_key] unless 
args.empty?
  end

  def [](k)
    if self.has_key?k
      super(k)
    else
      AutoHash.new(:update => self, :update_key => k)
    end
  end

  def []=(k, v)
    @update[@update_index] = self if @update and @update_index
    super
  end

  def few(n=0)
    Array.new(n) { AutoHash.new }
  end
end
```

This class allows to do the following things

```
a = AutoHash.new
a[:a][:b] = 1
p a[:c] # => {}             # key :c has not been created
p a     # => {:a=>{:b=>1}}  # note, that it does not have key :c

a,b,c = AutoHash.new.few 3
b[:d] = 1
p [a,b,c] # => [{}, {:d=>1}, {}]  # hashes are independent
```

There is [a bit more advanced definition](http://pastie.org/private/ayj1vglvadv5bf8orza) of this class [proposed by Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165331/multiple-initialization-of-auto-vivifying-hashes-using-a-new-operator-in-ruby/3165571#3165571), which is a bit hard for me to understand.

**Problem**

There is one situation, where I think the new class can be improved. The following code fails with the error message `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for {}:AutoHash`

```
a = AutoHash.new
5.times { a[:sum] += 10 }
```

What would you do to handle it? Can one define `[]+=` operator?

---

**Related questions**

1. [Is auto-initialization of multi-dimensional hash array possible in Ruby, as it is in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148747/is-auto-initialization-of-multi-dimensional-hash-array-possible-in-ruby-as-it-is)
2. [Multiple initialization of auto-vivifying hashes using a new operator in Ruby
   ruby hash initialization r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165331/multiple-initialization-of-auto-vivifying-hashes-using-a-new-operator-in-ruby)
3. **still open:** [How to create an operator for deep copy/cloning of objects in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171118/how-to-create-an-operator-for-deep-copy-cloning-of-objects-in-ruby)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the last piece of code, and what do you want to happen? If you want `a[:sum]` to be 50, you will have to initialize it to zero before the `5.times` line, because there is no way for `AutoHash` to know that you want to store numbers in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to define a `[]+=` method in ruby. What happens when you type

```
x[y] += z
```

is

```
x[y] = x[y] + z
```

so both the `[]` and `[]=` methods are called on `x` (and `+` is called on `x[y]`, which in this case is an `AutoHash`). I think that the best way to handle this problem would be to define a `+` method on `AutoHash`, which will just return it's argument. This will make `AutoHash.new[:x] += y` work for just about any type of `y`, because the "empty" version of `y.class` (`''` for strings, `0` for numbers, ...) plus `y` will almost always equal `y`.

```
class AutoHash
  def +(x); x; end
end
```

Adding that method will make both of these work:

```
# Numbers:
a = AutoHash.new
5.times { a[:sum] += 10 }
a[:sum] #=> 50

# Strings:
a = AutoHash.new
5.times { a[:sum] += 'a string ' }
a[:sum] #=> "a string a string a string a string a string "
```

And by the way, here is a cleaner version of your code:

```
class AutoHash < Hash
  def initialize(args={})
    super
    @update, @update_index = args[:update], args[:update_key]
  end

  def [](k)
    if has_key? k
      super(k)
    else
      AutoHash.new :update => self, :update_key => k
    end
  end

  def []=(k, v)
    @update[@update_index] = self if @update and @update_index
    super
  end

  def +(x); x; end

  def self.few(n)
    Array.new(n) { AutoHash.new }
  end
end
```

:)

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, Adrian! For a moment I was thinking about the case when `a[:sum]` has already a value of a different type, but then I realize that such raise of exception is a good thing to have.

Comment: @Andrei: When `a[:sum]` has a value that is not a `AutoHash`, the exception will be raised. For example: `a = AutoHash.new; a[:x] = 5; a[:x] += 'str'` will raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want is this:

`hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }`

`hash['foo'] += 3`
`# => 3`

That will return 3, then 6, etc. without an error, because the the new value is default assigned 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'xkeys' # on rubygems.org

a = {}.extend XKeys::Hash
a[:a, :b] = 1
p a[:c] # => nil (key :c has not been created)
p a # => { :a => { :b => 1 } }

a.clear
5.times { a[:sum, :else => 0] += 10 }
p a # => { :sum => 50 }
```